# Reading data from a server and detecting network unavailability in C#

Tags: c#, java, io, network-programming

I have a simple task: to read data from a server, if the server is unreachable (server down or bad network), load data (possibly stale) from local disk cache.

Here's a simple pseudo representation of what the Java code would look like:

```
try {
    //read from server
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    //most likely a socket timeout exception

    //read from local disk
} finally {
    //free I/O resources
}
```

but implementing that in C# doesn't seem to work as `WebClient` doesn't seem to throw any exception even when there's no internet access on the host machine so there's no way to detect that condition via the catch block and revert back to the local cache.
I'm aware of `WebClient`'s async APIs and its rather funny callback chain but I perceive this as too awkward and doesn't suit my design goal properly. Is there a way I can do this in C# as easily as the Java skeleton code shown above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebClient will timeout, but only after 100s.

I would recommend you use HttpWebRequest instead.  This has a settable timeout property.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx

Comment: Works! I find the Visual C# environment very unfriendly when it comes to documentations (the kind you see from Netbeans/Eclipse on Java). Please does the `HttpWebRequest` also raise a `WebException` in cases of network failures? I really need this to switch my app to offline mode. Thanks.

Comment: GetResponse() will return a WebException on timeout, yes.  See: [HttpWebRequest.GetResponse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse)

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore to bobbymond's answer, it's a WebException that will be returned by the WebClient, so that's what you're looking to catch:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
try
{
    wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Administrator", "SomePasword", "SomeDomain");
    byte[] aspx = wc.DownloadData("http://SomeServer/SomeSub/SomeFile.aspx");
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    //Catches any error in the WebClient, including an inability to contact the remote server
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: upvote for the `WebException` clarification. I was thinking `IOException` should be some sort of superclass for it though.

Comment: Cheers for that, appreciated. Yes, it's a shame it can't be more specific -- I've had that issue too -- and I'd love to hear from anyone who knows a better way.